# If every continuous real valued function on a metric space $X$ takes on extreme values, then $X$ is compact - difficulty following Royden's proof

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

$\newcommand{\d}{\operatorname{d}}$Royden's real analysis, page $201$, $4$th edition.

The tools at our disposal are that we know for metric spaces that $X$ compact is equivalent to $X$ sequentially compact and "$X$ is complete and totally bounded".

In Royden's proof there is a step I don't understand:

> If $X$ is not totally bounded, then there is an $r\gt0$ *and a countable subset $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset X$* for which $\{B(x_n,r):n\in\Bbb N\}$ is pairwise disjoint.

His definition of totally bounded is that for any $r\gt0$, **finitely** many balls can be chosen of radius $r$ which cover $X$. If $X$ is not totally bounded, then there is an $r$ for which no finite collection of balls covers $X$, but how one chooses a *disjoint* and countable *in*finite family of balls from this I know not.

I have spent a depressingly long time trying to prove it myself, by using the total boundedness of $f(X)$ in $\Bbb R$ to show $X$ is totally bounded, or by using the compactness of $f(\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\})\subset\Bbb R$ to show that every sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence - to no avail. I tried with the specific idea of $f_y:x\mapsto\d(x,y)$, showing that infinitely many $x_n$ from the sequence must satisfy $|\d(x_n,y)-\d(y_1,y)|\lt r$ for any $r\gt0$ and some $y_1$ *dependent on $r$*, but couldn't extend that to showing the subsequence converged. I can't even show my attempts because they were all in my head, and fell apart as soon as I tried to write them down.

Could someone explain his statement, or hint to me how to do this myself?

Comment: Construct them by induction?

Comment: Note if a collection of points are "$r$-separated", the  $r/2$-balls centered at those points. are mutually disjoint. So finding an infinite $r$-separated sequence (with $r>0$) will  suffice.

Comment: Done. It took me a while to see how the induction could work @DavidMitra, thank you